# Exception when closing WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, event-handling

I'm creating and showing a new window this way :

```
GammeDetail gammeDetail = new GammeDetail(_barCode, userID);
gammeDetail.ShowDialog();
```

In the constructor of the class `GammeDetail` I'm trying to do that :

```
try
{
     this._numLot = barcode.Substring(0, barcode.Length - 2); ;
     this._numGamme = barcode.Substring(barcode.Length - 2);
}
catch
{
     this.Close();
}
```

But that throws the following exception   `Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed.` on `gammeDetail.ShowDialog();`

I've another function which is an event handling function but does close the current window as you can see below :

```
private void newScan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      this.Close();
 }
```

In this case it works perfectly as I want, I tried to make the same function but without making of it an event handler but it throws the same previous exception.

I don't understand why it doesn't throws any exception when the function is an event handler.

If you have any idea, I'd be glad to hear them.
(if you need a specific piece of code to help, feel free to ask instead of downvoting without helping..)

Comment: I suspect there is unhandled exception in `try { }` block. set breakpoint `in catch { this.Close(); }`. your code should not "handle" possible exceptions like this, because it simply cannot handle it - external code sent invalid argument value, validate it and throw ArgumentException.

Comment: Why are you trying to close the window before it has even been created?

Comment: Because in my constructor I'm making some calls to a service which returns me some informations that I want to display on the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to try to close the window before it has even been created. Before the constructor has returned there is no window to be closed.

You should handle any exception in the code where you create an instance of the window:

```
GammeDetail gammeDetail;
try
{
    gammeDetail = new GammeDetail(_barCode, userID);
    gammeDetail.ShowDialog();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //the window was never opened...
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add you should specify your Exception if you know what to expect, moreover here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/

Comment: Yes, I'm stupid, I only thought about it when I saw the answer of Verendus, so obviously I did the same as in your answer, thanks a lot ! It didn't came in my mind that the constructor hasn't been fully executed before I closed my window so it's logical that it threw an exception...

Comment: @FreekW. Well in this case I know what is the exception but let's imagine that this part of code generate another exception in a very specific case that I would have forgot to test, it wouldn't catch it right ?

Comment: That's correct, if you do not know what to expect you shouldn't use a specific exception handler, but since you are going to want to know what kind of errors to expect, you might want to consider a specified exception.
This is also a reason why a catch all is commonly seen as bad practice.

Comment: Well in my application I'm initalizing the values I want to display in the constructor to display them when the windows shows, if the informations are not correct then I close the window and I catch the exception. I guess there is a cleaner way to do it programmatically but I don't know what's the best practice in this case, do you have any tips to give about it please ?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is an exception in your constructor, the window is closing, and then you try to use .ShowDialog() on a closed window. 
You need to handle the exception or check if the window is not already closed before calling .ShowDialog()

Comment: Thanks you, that was kind of a stupid question but I didn't realise what was the problem